# Rebooting a DFS Server

Tags: dfs-r

Server A and B have DFS-R.

If I want to reboot Server B and all clients connect to server A, do I need to disable folder targets for Server B still?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a REBOOT?

No, just reboot it. You may get small outages if they are the only targets - otherwise clients fall over - but you can do that ona weekend or evening.

Comment: Yeah there were a few software updates and requires a restart. I just don't want to kill any replication if it was occuring during reboot. I guess doing so after hours would be better. Just need to do it remotely.

Comment: Replications is made to be durable and survive that ;)